# node.js test case when response is {}

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, sinon

When I call an API to make a delete request, it returns `{}` as `request.body.result`.  I need to assert that the returned value `{}` is equal to my `MOCK_RESPONSE`:

```
{ 
result:{}
}
```

The test fails with the following error:

```
expected {} to equal {}
```

This is true; but how could I pass this test, since the expected response is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use `.deep`

Chai has [`.deep`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_deep), so you can do:

```
assert(
  actualResponse
).to.deep.equal(
  expectedResponse
)
```

`.equal` uses `===` equality, but the `.deep` segment changes that behavior:

> Causes all .equal, .include, .members, .keys, and .property assertions that follow in the chain to use deep equality instead of strict (===) equality. See the deep-eql project page for info on the deep equality algorithm: https://github.com/chaijs/deep-eql.